# Unable to run testcontainer from Windows Server 2019 (LinuxKit installed)

Tags: docker, testcontainers, windows-server-2019, linuxkit

Unable to run linux containers from testcontainer in Windows Server 2019 (LinuxKit installed). Getting errors as mentioned below.

```
2020-07-01 20:12:59.342 ERROR 4936 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
2020-07-01 20:12:59.342 ERROR 4936 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       :     NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (ping failed). Root cause TimeoutException (null)
2020-07-01 20:12:59.342 ERROR 4936 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       :     WindowsClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception TimeoutException (org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException). Root cause TimeoutException (null)
2020-07-01 20:12:59.342 ERROR 4936 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
```

Docker Info as below:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  cluster: Manage Docker clusters (Docker Inc., v1.2.0)

Server:
 Containers: 4
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 6
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
  Windows:
  LCOW:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Standard Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.1294)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 16GiB
 Name: DHUBAS204
 ID: ZWHK:7HAM:2IKC:YTDS:RD7L:P2V6:6ECL:A2I3:X6T2:2N33:3KSQ:ZX24
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: -1
  Goroutines: 31
  System Time: 2020-07-01T14:00:30.2657542+10:00
  EventsListeners: 0
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  registry-1.docker.io
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://hub-proxy.upm.asx.com.au/
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

PS:- Able to run linux containers without any issues from docker cli commands

Answer (score 0):

No support for windows servers.
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2960